# Alternative to inheritance from a generic parameter in Swift

Tags: c++, swift, templates, generics, inheritance

I'm quite new to Swift and recently noticed that you cannot inherit from a generic in Swift, e.g.

```
class MyClass<T> : T {}
```

is not valid in Swift 3 (see question [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508284/swift-inherit-from-generic-type)).

Here is the problem I was hoping to solve with the above construct:

```
protocol Backend {
  func operationA(operand: Int)
}

class ConcreteBackend : Backend {

  func operationA(operand: Int) {
    // ...
  }

  // Some other functions and/or custom initializers
  // ...
}

class EnhancedBackend<T : Backend> : T {

  override func operationA(operand: Int) {
    // do something smart here
    super.operationA(operand: modifiedOperand)
  }
}
```

Basically `EnhancedBackend` does something smart with the input of `operationA` and then passes it to the actual implementation of `Backend`.
I'm using inheritance here instead of composition, because `ConcreteBackend` might have some public properties, functions and initializers that are not specified in the protocol (because they are only related to the concrete implementation) that I want to also expose with `EnhancedBackend`.
Without inheritance this would not be possible.

A C++ implementation might look like

```
// Using concepts here instead of protocols
class ConrecteBackend {
  public:
    void operationA(int operand) { .... }
}

template<class T>
class EnhancedBackend : public T {
  using Base = T;
  public:
    // Ensure T is a model of the Backend concept
    static_assert(isModelOfConceptBackend<T>::value,
                  "Template parameter is not a model of concept Backend");

    // Ensure all constructors of Base can be used
    template<class ...Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<
      std::is_constructible<Base, Args...>::value>>
    inline EnhancedBackend(Args &&...args) : Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    void operationA(int operand) {
      // ...
      Base::operationA(operand);
    }
};
```

So with C++ it's quite simple to solve the problem. But at the moment I have no clue how to implement in with (pure) Swift 3.

Comment: Have you checked out this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508284/swift-inherit-from-generic-type?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Grimxn that Q&A is spot on, but already linked to by the OP right after his first code snippet above :)

Comment: @dfri - oops! :) Just read to the bottom - OP even commented on that question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift's generics are not the same as C++ templates which are closer to pre processing macros than Swift's type semantics.

There are however a number of ways to achieve similar results.  One way if to use variables to reference functions that need customized dispatching rules:

for example:

```
protocol Backend:class
{
  var operationA:(Int) -> () { get set }

  func performOperationA(_ : Int) -> ()
}

class ConcreteBackend : Backend 
{
  lazy var operationA:(Int) -> () = self.performOperationA 

  func performOperationA(_ : Int) -> ()
  {
    // ...
  }

  // Some other functions and/or custom initializers
  // ...
}

extension Backend
{
  var enhancedForTesting:Self
  {
     operationA = testing_OperationA 
     return self
  }

  func testing_OperationA(_ operand:Int) -> ()
  {
    let modifiedOperand = operand + 1
    performOperationA(modifiedOperand)
  }

}

let enhancedBackend = ConcreteBackend().enhancedForTesting
```

By using a variable to reference the function's implementation, it becomes possible to dynamically change the behaviour of operationA at runtime and for specific instances.

In this example, the enhancements are added to the Backend protocol but they could also have been set by an independent function or even another class that has its own particular kind of altered behaviour.

When using this approach, the instance has all the attributes and functions of the concrete class while implementing the enhanced behaviour for the altered functions of the protocol.

Creating the enhanced instance uses a syntax that is as simple as (if not simpler than) a generic class constructor:

```
// for example:

let instance = ConcreteBackend(...).enhanced

// rather than:

let instance = EnhancedBackend<ConcreteBackEnd>(...)
```