# conform to generic type D whic is a protocol

Tags: ios, generics, swift3, swift4

I have a base view controller that all Viewcontrollers will inherit from it and i want to conform to generic type D which is a protocol but i get

> Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'D'

&

> 'type' is not a member type of 'D'

Here is my code

```
open class BaseViewController <T, D> :
                                UIViewController,
                                D,
                                ViewControllerCommonFeatures
                                where T : BasePresenter<D>, D.type == Protocol {
}
```

Base Presenter is a normal swift class and D will be a swift protocol that conforms to other swift protocol.

I want at least to define D type as protocol.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your class can't inherit from a generic (or conform to a generic protocol), that's not how if works. The classes base class and the protocols it conforms to must be known at compile time. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @mag_zbc i want to pass a protocol D the conform to it (I want to use it between <> brackets and conform to it at the same time)

Comment: I haven’t downvoted anything. I just flagged it as a possible duplicate.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri ok, thank you

Comment: I can see _what_ are you trying to do, I'm asking _for what purpose?_, because what you are doing is not possible, period.

Comment: I'm implementing generic Model view presenter and i want to save the duplicate @mag_zbc i'm implementing generic MVP and i want to do to the repeated work repeated work so i want whoever extends  the BaseViewController to passes the presenter and the protocol between the <> brackets, then it will automatically conform to the protocol which is passed in between the <> brackets.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508284/swift-inherit-from-generic-type), it seems that what i'm trying to do is not doable in Swift as swift forbids extending or conforming to Generic type.
A known type must be specified before compilation the code.

Comment: No point repeating the answer to the existing question. A kinder strategy might be to reduce bandwidth by deleting your question.

Comment: What if someone tried to implement what i was trying to do, don't you think that it will be useful and straight forward to him ! + It is a little bit not the exact same case.